# How to add dimension to a python numpy array

Tags: numpy

Let's suppose i have this array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(4)

array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

I want to write a very basic formula which will generate from x this array:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

What is the shortest way to do that with python and numpy ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure it's a dupe of that, @Divakar.  Looks like he may want `x[None, :] + x[:, None]`  Which is probably a dupe of something else, simple as it is.

Comment: @DanielF Using a `stepsize=1` solves, it, doesn't it?

Comment: Not from the original `x` array he specified.  There are no `4,5,6` elements to stride to using `stride_tricks`

Comment: @DanielF Ah yes, thanks! Reopened.

Comment: @Bob5421 What's the criteria of adding a dimension here?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to use numpy broadcasting.

```
x[:,None]+x
Out[87]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want (note that I have introduced a different number of rows (5) than of columns (4) to make a clear distinction):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.tile(np.arange(4).reshape(1,4),(5,1))+np.tile(np.arange(5).reshape(5,1),(1,4))

print(A)
```

A break-down of steps:

1. `np.tile(np.arange(4).reshape(1,4),(5,1))` creates a (5,4) matrix with entries 0,1,2,3 in each row:

   ```
   [[0 1 2 3]
    [0 1 2 3]
    [0 1 2 3]
    [0 1 2 3]
    [0 1 2 3]]
   ```
2. `np.tile(np.arange(5).reshape(5,1),(1,4))` creates a (5,4) matrix with 0,1,2,3,4 in each column:

   ```
   [[0 0 0 0]
    [1 1 1 1]
    [2 2 2 2]
    [3 3 3 3]
    [4 4 4 4]]
   ```
3. The sum of the two results in what you want:

   ```
   [[0 1 2 3]
    [1 2 3 4]
    [2 3 4 5]
    [3 4 5 6]
    [4 5 6 7]]
   ```